# How to create multiple dataframes from multiple lists/dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, for-loop

I have multiple dictionaries containing different measurements/calculations based on the same 14 sets of data. Each dictionary has the same set of keys, defined by

```
group_list =['A', 'B', 'C','D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N']
```

I have created the dictionaries based on calculations and manipulating data from other dictionaries + lists prior to this.  The dictionaries in question are

```
speed_dict
output_dict
output2_dict
```

These are created outside of the for loop and then filled as to give an output of something similar to

```
speed_dict = {'A': [list of speeds for A], 'B': [list of speeds for B]... etc for letters up to 'N':[list of speeds for N]}
output_dict = {'A': [output of function for A], 'B':[output of function for B].... 'N':[output of function for N]}
output2_dict = {'A':[output of func for A squared]....}
```

I'm sure you get the picture. The length of each value/list in each dictionary is 8 items long.

I am looking for a way to create 14 separate dataframes for each set of data, A to N, with each column containing a different data set (I have managed to correctly produce my desired result for the last set of data only [the last set of data only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhsKS.png) (speed is titled velocity and output is lift coefficient) using this code:

```py
group_list = ['A', 'B', 'C','D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N']

speed_dict = {}
output_dict = {}
output_dict = {}
cl_dataframe = []

for i in range(0, len(group_list)):
    speed_dict.update({group_list[i]: constant*some_dict.get(group_list[i])})
    output_dict.update({group_list[i]: some_func(speed_dict.get(group_list[i]))})
    output2_dict.update({group_list[i]: (output_dict.get(group_list[i]))**2})

    output_dataframe.append({"Equivalent Velocity": list(speed_dict.get(group_list[i])),
                   "Lift Coefficient": list(output_dict.get(group_list[i])),
                   "Lift Coefficient Squared": list(output_dict.get(group_list[i]))})

pd.DataFrame(output_dataframe[i], columns=["Equivalent Velocity", "Lift Coefficient", "Lift Coefficient Squared"])
```

In the final line, if I take away the [i] and instead use

```
pd.DataFrame(output_dataframe, columns=["Equivalent Velocity", "Lift Coefficient", "Lift Coefficient Squared"])
```

[I instead get this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZR2B.png). If I keep the [i] and indent the line, so that this process occurs within the for loop, I receive no output from Python, no errors and no table. Is there a way of creating the 14 separate dataframes, one for each key/'letter', similar to the dataframe output for the submitted code above [(here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhsKS.png), where each column is a separate dictionary? 
Thanks

edit: reworded entire question

Comment: Please be precise in your question, there is very much left for imagination. You are looking to combine three dictionaries, but you have mentioned only one data_dict_1. Then group_lists ? what kind of value is that? It would be better to answer, if you can provide what your input looks like, What output expected and what it is currently.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Please see the edit above, I have reworded the whole question to make it more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
group_list = ['A', 'B', 'C','D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N']

# dummy data
speed_dict = {a: np.random.randint(0,10,10) for a in group_list}
output_dict = {a: np.random.randint(0,10,10) for a in group_list}
output2_dict = {a: np.random.randint(0,10,10) for a in group_list}

# convert dict to dataframes
dataframes = [pd.DataFrame(d) for d in [speed_dict, output_dict, output2_dict]]

# extract respective column from all dataframes and combine in individual df
single_dataframes = [pd.concat([d[column] for d in dataframes], axis=1) for column in group_list]
#rename columns
for sdf in single_dataframes:
    sdf.columns=['Equivalent Velocity','Lift Coefficient', 'Lift Coefficient Squared']
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have reworded the whole question to be more precise in what I am asking for

Comment: @SixChickensInATrenchcoat IIUC this should be what you want

Comment: glad to help :)